# Prestashop: trying to decode password

Tags: asp.net, mysql, prestashop

i'm developing a backend in Asp.NET for Prestashop. I've a small problem: can't decode password ! 
Here the code

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ps_employee WHERE email=@email AND passwd=MD5(@pwd) AND active=1"
```

As you can see, i'm using MYSQL MD5 function, but ... it not work.. Password is correct, i'm sure...

Comment: You are not trying to decode the password (it is not possible) but to encode it to verify it. Beside, I would make the request with the passwd, and verify it afterward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The password hash is [salted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), prestashop seems to be using the value [_COOKIE_KEY_](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/67770/) in `settings.inc.php` for this.

You will have to look up this value and compute the md5 hash of it and the password concatenated: `md5(@COOKIE_KEY.@pwd)`

Comment: The salt is only a matter of string concatenation, mysql supports that.

Comment: @stighy: yes, I guess sthg like this : SELECT 1 FROM ps_customer WHERE email = :login AND passwd = md5(concat('my_cookie_key', :password))

Comment: works like a charm.. I have to add:
- settings.inc.php is in directory public_html/config/ or www/config/ (hope it is the same on your server);
- to calculate md5 of saltpassword I used http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/ .

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature built into PrestaShop. You will not be able to decode any encoded passwords.