# Prestashop - How is encrypted the db password?

Tags: php, encryption, prestashop-1.6

File name: `/config/settings.inc.php`, this file includes `server`, `dbname`, `dbuser`, `dbpassword`, etc...

This is the line which I am having problems:

```
define('_DB_PASSWD_', '(x02SPOv(1');
```

I don't know how is encrypted that value, I tried MD5, because is the way the user's passwords are stored in the users table `((value + key)->md5)`, but it didn't work.

Any idea which is the encryption of this field?

Comment: a better question is "what are you trying to do". Because that password doesn't look hashed at all, it's way too short. It just looks like "the actual password".

Comment: So hard to google the documentation,the password is also salted with _COOKIE_KEY_ https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/51589-forgotten-lost-password-manual-reset-via-phpmyadmin/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903170/prestashop-trying-to-decode-password

Comment: @gabriel Could you please provide more informations on what you're trying to achieve? For the moment your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is not encrypted at all. It's an actual password for the database. You can find more information about the config files here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/System+Administrator+Guide#SystemAdministratorGuide-MySQLconfiguration

Comment: The question is confusing,but I think he`s asking about the process that password goes before being stored in the db.

Comment: Voitek is right, this password is not encrypted. It is used to log in MySql. gabriel should provide more informations on what he is actually trying to do as his question is actually unclear.